# manifold tangent vector spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

i need help, i need to prove these two proposition but i did not have any idea about how should i start for proof:

1)let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $N\subset M$ is sub-manifold of $M$. prove that
$$TN\subset TM$$
2)If $M$ be a smooth manifold and oriented then $TM$ is oriented too.

i really have problem to start solving manifold problems and didn't have any idea about proof of those questions,please help me for solution of them.thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

1. (Assuming you defines $T$ in terms of equivalent classes of smooth curves.)
   For $x\in N$, we have a canonical linear map $T_xN\to T_xM$, which is induced by the fact that every curve $\gamma\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to N$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ can also be viewed as $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ (and clearly, equivalent curves in the sense of the definition of $T_xN$ map to equivalent curves in the sense of the definition of $T_xM$). Remains to show that this canonical linear map is injective, thereby allowing us to view $T_xN$ as subspace of $T_xM$. From this statement for stalks, transfer first to small neighbourhoods (i.e., consider small open $U\subset M$ such that both $U$ and $U\cap N$ are contractible), and ultimately to the global tangential bundle.
2. Given an orientable atlas of $M$ (i.e., such that the Jacobian of transition maps between charts has positive determinant), you can readily construct such an atlas for $TM$.

Comment: thank you for answer,it is useful for me but the answer of second question is misty, finding such an orient able atlas is hard for me cause i am the beginner of manifold student.

Comment: and for first answer, i think this problem has a solution with preferred charts or transformation maps.thank you @Hagen von Eitzen